# What is the paradigm of wrapping generic parameters into nested structures called?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, paradigms, type-theory

Consider this design:

```cpp
template <typename IndexOrder>
struct MatrixBase {
    using ValueType = IndexOrder::ValueType;
    // This struct provides the public interface
};

template <typename StorageProvider>
struct RowMajorOrder {
    using ValueType = StorageProvider::ValueType;
    // This struct provides functions to map 2D coordinates to 1D offset
};
template <typename StorageProvider>
struct ColMajorOrder {
    using ValueType = StorageProvider::ValueType;
    // This struct provides functions to map 2D coordinates to 1D offset
};

template <typename T>
struct OwnedStorage {
    typedef T ValueType;
    // This struct manages the allocation of a continuous block of memory
};
template <typename T>
struct BorrowedStorage {
    typedef T ValueType;
    // This struct stores a pointer to a block of memory managed by others
};

// The type aliases are responsible for the wrapping
template <typename T>
using MatrixRowMajor = MatrixBase<RowMajorOrder<OwnedStorage<T>>>;
template <typename T>
using MatrixColMajor = MatrixBase<ColMajorOrder<OwnedStorage<T>>>;
template <typename T>
using MatrixRowMajorView = MatrixBase<RowMajorOrder<BorrowedStorage<T>>>;
template <typename T>
using MatrixColMajorView = MatrixBase<ColMajorOrder<BorrowedStorage<T>>>;
```

When the user needs to use the type, they write:

```cpp
MatrixRowMajor<double> my_matrix;
```

Instead of making `T` a type parameter of `MatrixBase`, this design wraps `T` into nested layers of structures.

The type `MatrixBase` receives the wrapped nested structures instead of `T` directly. Whenever `MatrixBase` needs to refer to `T`, it uses the associated type `ValueType`.

Lastly, the user uses the provided type aliases `MatrixRowMajor` etc. The user only provides `T`. Those type aliases are responsible for the wrapping.

**Question:** What is this design paradigm called? Do we have a name for it?

(A similar design is also used in the Rust library [ndarray](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/index.html#types).)

Comment: "Traits class"?  See for example `std::allocator_traits` and `std::iterator_traits`

Comment: Or do you mean the way `StorageProvider` is chosen through a template parameter?  It's one approach to "aspect-oriented programming".  It might also be called "policy composition".

Comment: BTW questions about design patterns are better for Software Engineering Stack Exchange: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I want to emphasis the design we pass `T` through inner structures, instead of the traditional way through the outer structure. This relies on the capability of the type system provided by the language. So I consider this question only 50% related to Software Engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [Policy Based Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design#Policy-based_design)

Comment: According to Wikipedia, poly based design perfectly matches the nested structures. And I agree that if that’s the only stuff, we can sure categorize my question into Software Engineering field.
**But just before I accept your answer.** Here is a followup question and it may be related to Type System or Type Theory: What about `T`?
Normally we pass `T` to the top-level structure, instead of the inner-level structures. This depends on that the type system allows us to do it and isn’t applicable to all languages. And it’s not described in your linked Wikipedia article.

Comment: By the way, thank you for this answer! I learned a lot through your linked article. I still want to wait for a few days before closing the question (in hope someone can teach me about the `T`).